# iOS ( iPhone / iPad ) - exporting csv from slite3 database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, sqlite

Does anyone know how to export a CSV file from a SQLite3 database in an iPhone app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several iOS CSV libraries that can be used to export the data from the phone. This is a trivial data transformation task - you read the information line-by-line from the SQLite result set, and send it out into the CSV file. If you do not need to process the file after the complete read-in, then you should be able to stream the data as quickly as it is read.

Writing CSV files is mostly trivial - and can be implemented by someone without much effort. I'm certain there are libraries for iOS specifically, but I've used the python CSV export routines regularly, and they have been read by excel without much effort. You just have to be careful, as excel has the habit of interpreting the results once they are in there, making some accuracy calculations impossible.

the .csv file format is trivial, and I've implemented it several times in several languages. if you have numeric requirements, though, you will be spending a lot of time making sure that the program that you feed it into is accepting the numbers properly - and you will have to deal with 'I imported it into excel, saved it and the data is wrong now' bugs...